# Replcae string using table in pywin32 of Python like =IFS(A1='CA','California',A1='AL', 'Alabama',A1='NY', 'New York')

Tags: python, excel, pywin32

Newbie here

I assume this is a case like when you want to use translate(string.maketrans) but you want to replace some words with more than a character.

I'm trying to automate simple excel task, where is required to translate/replace certain words.

I know there are many ways to do this such as with for loop or excel formula itself when I'm using win32 but I tried below thinking it's more simple and just don't logically understand why it cannot work.

```
trans={'CA':'California','TX':'Texas','NY':'New York'}  
wb2.Range('F10').value=str(wb1.Range('F2')).translate(trans)
```

<strike>Returns no errors but happens nothing in wb2.Range('F10')</strike>  
→actually value of F2(in sheet1) will be just copied to F10(in sheet2) without replacement.

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: If i understand correctly f2 has `CA\TX\NY` and in f10 you want to have `California\Texas\New York` right?

Comment: Hi @venky__
yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the data in dictionary you can directly call it as `dict[element]`.

```
>>> trans['CA']
>>> 'California'
```

Code:

```
trans={'CA':'California','TX':'Texas','NY':'New York'}  
wb2.Range('F10').value= trans[str(wb1.Range('F2'))]
```

Comment: I knew this would be simpler! Everybody writes how you can translate strings of a whole data but I was missing this basic. Thank you very much this is just what I wanted.